# How do configure Oracle GoldenGate OracleDB init loading?

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I'm trying to replicate the Oracle Database in the Oracle Database. I'm using the next command initing a replication:

```
SOURCEISTABLE
SOURCEDB mydb, USERIDALIAS ogg
RMTHOSTOPTIONS ny4387, MGRPORT 7888, ENCRYPT AES 192 KEYNAME mykey
ENCRYPTTRAIL AES192
RMTFILE /ggs/dirdat/initld, MEGABYTES 2, PURGE
TABLE hr.*;
TABLE sales.*;
```

And I would like to know what is **RMTHOSTOPTIONS** and how is it configureing in a remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manager of Oraсle Golden Gate after installation will not configure. To further access the Golden Gate, configure its manager:

1. There is please create next directories in the Golden Gate directory:

```
gg>mkdir dirprm
gg>mkdir dirrpt
gg>mkdir dirpcs
```

2. Set Oracle paths:

```
>ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
>export ORACLE_HOME
>ORACLE_SID=XE
>export ORACLE_SID
```

3.Login into DB:

```
gg> ./ggsci
GGSCI> DBLOGIN USERID system, PASSWORD 123123
```

4. Please create the params file of the manager:

```
GGSCI> EDIT PARAMS MGR
```

5. the file:

```
PORT 7809
USERID system, PASSWORD 123123
AUTORESTART ER *, RETRIES 3, WAITMINUTES 3, RESETMINUTES 10
PURGEOLDEXTRACTS ./dirdat/*, USECHECKPOINTS
LAGCRITICALMINUTES 5
LAGREPORTMINUTES 60
LAGINFOMINUTES 0
```

6. Start manager:

```
GGSCI> start manager
```

see [Init Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-KiXvZtscM) after configureing OGG manager.